# $relatedQuery method doesn't return modal entity

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, node-postgres, objection.js

I use PostgreSQL and [objection.js](https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/) for ORM. When I use [$relatedQuery](http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/#_s_relatedquery) method, I get [QueryBuilder](http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/#querybuilder) object instead of Model entities.

[Here](https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/blob/49159b6168902e5951aa9e9796da79dbae035ba4/examples/express-es6/api.js#L177) is example project and how to use `$relatedQuery` method.

**podcastListener.js**

```
const { Model, snakeCaseMappers } = require('objection');

class Podcast extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return 'podcasts_listeners';
  }

  static get columnNameMappers() {
    return snakeCaseMappers();
  }

  static get jsonSchema() {
    return {
      type: 'object',

      properties: {
        id: { type: 'integer' },
        name: { type: 'string', minLength: 1, maxLength: 100 },
      },
    };
  }

  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      usersRel: {
        relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
        modelClass: `${__dirname}/user`,
        join: {
          from: 'podcasts_listeners.user_id',
          to: 'users.id',
        },
      },

      episodesRel: {
        relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
        modelClass: `${__dirname}/episode`,
        join: {
          from: 'podcasts_listeners.id',
          to: 'episodes.podcasts_listeners_id',
        },
      },
    };
  }
}

module.exports = Podcast;
```

**episode.js**

```
const { Model, snakeCaseMappers } = require('objection');

class Episode extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return 'episodes';
  }

  static get columnNameMappers() {
    return snakeCaseMappers();
  }

  static get jsonSchema() {
    return {
      type: 'object',

      properties: {
        podcasts_listeners_id: { type: 'integer' },
        id: { type: 'integer' },
        episode_name: { type: 'string', minLength: 1, maxLength: 100 }, },
        description: { type: 'string' },
      },
    };
  }

  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      podcastRel: {
        relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
        modelClass: `${__dirname}/podcastListener`,
        join: {
          from: 'episodes.podcasts_listeners_id',
          to: 'podcasts_listeners.id',
        },
      },
    };
  }
}

module.exports = Episode;
```

If I run:

```
const podcast = await PodcastListener.query()
    .findOne('name', podcastName);

  const episode = podcast
    .$relatedQuery('episodesRel')
    .findById(6);
```

or:

```
  const episode = podcast
    .$relatedQuery('episodesRel');
```

episode variable is `QueryBuilder` instead of `Episode` model.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing `await` :

```
const episode = await podcast
    .$relatedQuery('episodesRel');
```